# Business days between two dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, multiple-columns

I have two columns `"Blk Start"` and `"Blk End"` in a dataframe. I need to create the 3rd column by calculating the number of working days between two dates. I am using the below code, but its not working

```
df[x] = np.busday_count(df['Blk_start'],df['Blk_end'])
```

Do I need to use any other function?

The error from the above code is:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)  in  ----> 1 df[x] = np.busday_count(df['Blk_start'],df['Blk_end']) TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from `dtype('<M8[ns]')` to `dtype('<M8[D]')` according to the rule 'safe'

Column formats are:

```
fundmgr_id   int64 
user_name    object 
Blk_start.   datetime64[ns] 
Blk_end      datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Could you share an error code that you got or explain how your dataframe looks like. Checkout the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) from numpy and see if you can get it to work with just a simple example. It possibly has to do with the formatting of your data in those columns, or you have to loop apply over the dataframe to get it to work.

Comment: df[x] = np.busday_count(df['Blk_start'],df['Blk_end'])
df[x] = np.busday_count(df['Blk_start'],df['Blk_end'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-afe45df21038> in <module>
----> 1 df[x] = np.busday_count(df['Blk_start'],df['Blk_end'])

TypeError: Iterator operand 0 dtype could not be cast from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('<M8[D]') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: fundmgr_id              int64
user_name              object
Blk_start      datetime64[ns]
Blk_end        datetime64[ns]

Comment: In future, please add additional information by editing the question, not as comments.

Answer (score 1):

[np.busday_count](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) says it works on an *array_like of datetime64[D]* so you can cast the columns to that format first, then perform the operation.

```
en = df["Blk_end"].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
st = df["Blk_start"].values.astype('datetime64[D]')
df["x"] = np.busday_count(st, en)
```